# Flash Builder 4.5 file import issue

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, builder

I am new to Flex and Flash Builder 4.5. I was given the task to make changes to an existing file and compile it again to implement the changes.

I made the code changes, but recieve the following error when trying to export or run the project:

```
Unable to locate specified base class 'custom.GridComboBox' for component
class 'iStatsInnerClass2'.
```

Now the problem seems to be that it cant see the custom files used in the app, but it is pointing to it here:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    pageTitle="iStats" xmlns:comp="custom.*"
    xmlns:cust="custom.ComboCheck.*"
    creationComplete="initLogin()">
```

The files are located in the custom directory located in the src directory.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Try to show more of your code, you question can't be answered as is. The code snippet you've included is not enough. For example, show us where you actually use your custom component.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, actually the project didn't import correctly, when I reimported with the older Flex SDK in the properties it worked without a hitch.